# Is `x >> pure y` equivalent to `liftM (const y) x`

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

The two expressions

```hs
y >> pure x
liftM (const x) y
```

have the same type signature in Haskell.
I was curious whether they were equivalent, but I could neither produce a proof of the fact nor a counter example against it.

If we rewrite the two expressions so that we can eliminate the `x` and `y` then the question becomes whether the two following functions are equivalent

```hs
flip (>>) . pure
liftM . const
```

Note that both these functions have type `Monad m => a -> m b -> m a`.

I used the laws that Haskell gives for monad, applicatives, and functors to transform both statements into various equivalent forms, but I was not able to produce a sequence of equivalences between the two.

For instance I found that `y >> pure x` can be rewritten as follows

```hs
y >>= const (pure x)
y *> pure x
(id <$ y) <*> pure x
fmap (const id) y <*> pure x
```

and `liftM (const x) y` can be rewritten as follows

```hs
fmap (const x) y
pure (const x) <*> y
```

None of these spring out to me as necessarily equivalent, but I cannot think of any cases where they would not be equivalent.

Answer (score 14):

The other answer gets there eventually, but it takes a long-winded route. All that is actually needed are the definitions of `liftM`, `const`, and a single monad law: `m1 >> m2` and `m1 >>= \_ -> m2` must be semantically identical. (Indeed, this is the default implementation of `(>>)`, and it is rare to override it.) Then:

```
liftM (const x) y
= { definition of liftM* }
y >>= \z -> pure (const x z)
= { definition of const }
y >>= \z -> pure x
= { monad law }
y >> pure x
```

* Okay, okay, so the actual definition of `liftM` uses `return` instead of `pure`. Whatever.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason I thought that the standard definition was `liftM = fmap`, with the more restrictive type. With the real definition above, the wanted equation is much simpler to obtain :)

Comment: @chi Even without it things aren't too bad: `fmap f m = m >>= return . f` is also a monad law (one of the oft-forgotten ones).

Comment: That law itself follows from parametricity and the monad law `m >>= pure = m`.

Answer (score 11):

## Yes they are the same

Let's start with `flip (>>) . pure`, which is the pointfree version of `x >> pure y` you provide:

```
flip (>>) . pure
```

It is the case that `flip (>>)` is just `(=<<) . const` so we can rewrite this as:

```
((=<<) . const) . pure
```

Since function composition (`(.)`) is associative we can write this as:

```
(=<<) . (const . pure)
```

Now we would like to rewrite `const . pure`. We can notice that `const` is just `pure` on `(a ->)`, that means since `pure . pure` is `fmap pure . pure`, `const . pure` is `(.) pure . const`, (`(.)` is `fmap` for the functor `(a ->)`).

```
(=<<) . ((.) pure . const)
```

Now we associate again:

```
((=<<) . (.) pure) . const
```

`((=<<) . (.) pure)` is the definition for `liftM`<sup>1</sup> so we can substitute:

```
liftM . const
```

And that is the goal.  The two are the same.

---

<sup>1: The definition of `liftM` is `liftM f m1 = do { x1 <- m1; return (f x1) }`, we can desugar the `do` into `liftM f m1 = m1 >>= return . f`.  We can flip the `(>>=)` for `liftM f m1 = return . f =<< m1` and elide the `m1` to get `liftM f = (return . f =<<)` a little pointfree magic and we get `liftM = (=<<) . (.) return`</sup>

Comment: Can you please add how you get from `const . pure` to `fmap pure . const`? Btw it might have been easier to start with `(.)` right away instead of writing `fmap` (and later explaining (figuring out?) what `Functor` instance it belongs to).

Comment: @Bergi Actually you are right, doing it earlier makes things simpler.

Answer (score 4):

One more possible route, exploiting the applicative laws:

> For instance I found that `y >> pure x` can be rewritten as follows [...]
>
> ```
> fmap (const id) y <*> pure x
> ```

That amounts to...

```
fmap (const id) y <*> pure x
pure ($ x) <*> fmap (const id) y -- interchange law of applicatives
fmap ($ x) (fmap (const id) y) -- fmap in terms of <*>
fmap (($ x) . const id) y -- composition law of functors
fmap (const x) y
```

... which, as you noted, is the same as `liftM (const x) y`.

That this route requires only applicative laws and not monad ones reflects how `(*>)` (another name for `(>>)`) is an `Applicative` method.